# Where are the breaking changes for DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns() documented?

Tags: c#, datetime

Consider the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("EN-us");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()));
        }
    }
}
```

When targeting .net Core 3.1 (or .net Framework 4.8), this is displayed:

```
M/d/yyyy
M/d/yy
MM/dd/yy
MM/dd/yyyy
yy/MM/dd
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy
MMMM d, yyyy
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy
d MMMM, yyyy
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy H:mm
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt
MMMM d, yyyy H:mm
MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy H:mm
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
d MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
d MMMM, yyyy H:mm
d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
d MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt
M/d/yyyy H:mm
M/d/yyyy HH:mm
M/d/yy h:mm tt
M/d/yy hh:mm tt
M/d/yy H:mm
M/d/yy HH:mm
MM/dd/yy h:mm tt
MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt
MM/dd/yy H:mm
MM/dd/yy HH:mm
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt
MM/dd/yyyy H:mm
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
yy/MM/dd h:mm tt
yy/MM/dd hh:mm tt
yy/MM/dd H:mm
yy/MM/dd HH:mm
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
dd-MMM-yy h:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy H:mm
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm
M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss
M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss
M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy hh:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy H:mm:ss
M/d/yy HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt
yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt
yy/MM/dd H:mm:ss
yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss
MMMM d
MMMM d
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
h:mm tt
hh:mm tt
H:mm
HH:mm
h:mm:ss tt
hh:mm:ss tt
H:mm:ss
HH:mm:ss
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
d MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
d MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
d MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
d MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM yyyy
MMMM yyyy
```

However, when targeting .net 5.0 this is displayed:

```
M/d/yyyy
MMM d, yyyy
M/d/yy
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy
MMMM d, yyyy
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
MMM d, yyyy h:mm tt
M/d/yy h:mm tt
M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d
MMMM d
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
h:mm tt
h:mm:ss tt
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM yyyy
MMMM yyyy
```

Clearly this is a breaking change. I've looked for the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/5.0 but I can't find any mention of `GetAllDateTimePatterns()`.

Does anyone know where this change is documented?

(One specific issue we're having is that the list of patterns doesn't contain anything for `M/d/yy h:mm` - it only contains `M/d/yy h:mm tt` so that there has to be a am/pm indicator included for that format. In fact, all the formats that include hours and minutes also require an am/pm indicator.)

Comment: `tt` is not a time zone, it's the AM/PM designator. Using that doesn't seem like a bad idea at all when using 12 hour format -- and if you look closely at the original list, it consistently uses `tt` for all `h` patterns as well. The difference is that it also includes `HH` patterns for 24 hours (none of which include `tt`) while the new list omits these patterns (except for the ISO ones), presumably because `en-US` formats use AM/PM. The bigger mystery is probably why the original list has 24-hour patterns to begin with. This may be tied to regional settings of the machine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good point - I've corrected the text. I do agree that it's a good idea to have the am/pm for hh patterns (I think we're using that for all actual code - it's just some unit tests that are failing. I just need to fix the unit tests - but it would be nice to see some documentation somewhere about the changes!)

Comment: You can always use a custom pattern, both for formatting and for parsing, so I wonder why a list of standard patterns is even that interesting? As the page says "you cannot assume that the custom format strings returned by the GetAllDateTimePatterns method can be used to round-trip date and time values", which I interpret as "problems are to be expected, unless you take things fully into your own hands".

Comment: Be sure to have a critical look at your tests in any case -- as the remarks of the method note, that list produces a list of formats used when converting date/times to strings, but there's no roundtrip guarantee when these formats are used for parsing. I'm actually struggling to think of any *legitimate* application of `GetAllDateTimePatterns` without an argument (calling it with an argument to get a *specific* format seems more legit).

Comment: @PeterB Yes, this is some old legacy code I'm dealing with from 8 years ago.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree - this code is very dubious. And very old. This change will certainly make it more robust. :)

Comment: It's possible that it's actually part of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api - although that doesn't mention date/time formatting. See whether the switch in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu changes the behavior back to the old one... if so, that's the culprit :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes - setting that switch does indeed revert the behaviour! So that's actually the answer (kind of ;))